# Spring CrudRepository Insert values into mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I want to create a `@PostMapping`which executes an insert statement. Here is my code:

Repository (I have findAllBy functions that are working perfectly). Here is the insert function that obviously is not working. ->

```
@Transactional
@Query(value = "INSERT INTO recipes(title, description) VALUES (?1, ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
    void insertRecipes(String title, String description);

@PostMapping(path = "/all/create")
public void addRecipes(@RequestParam("title") String title, @RequestParam(value = "description") String description){
    Recipes recipe = new Recipes();
    recipe.setTitle(title);
    recipe.setDescription(description);
    repo.insertRecipes(recipe.getTitle(), recipe.getDescription());
}
```

I don't mention the recipes id because it's auto incremental. And here is my Entity ->

```
@Entity
public class Recipes {
@Column(name = "id")
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    //getters-setters and constructions below.
}
```

My problem is that I'm getting this exception -> `java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery()`

Any ideas?
PS. I have done all the connections correctly. All the GET methods are working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(
                value = "/all/create",
                method = RequestMethod.POST,
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
                produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<Recipes> create(
                @RequestBody Recipes recipes) {
            Recipes saved= recipesService.add(recipes);         
            return new ResponseEntity<Recipes>(saved, HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
```

**Service**

```
public Recipes add(Recipes recipes) {

    Recipes save = recipesRepository.save(recipes);
    return save;
}
```

> if you are dealing with the JSON, then you can use this and check using Postman

Answer (score 0):

With your code, Spring, and eventually `EntityManager` creates a `Query` object on which it invokes one of the query methods. This wont work as your are triggering an insert..

In order for it to invoke the `executeUpdate()`, which is what you are ultimately aiming for you would have to add `@Modifyng` annotation.